# Qual problema pode ocorrer ao retonar um valor sem ter uma variavel para receber (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Se eu tenho uma função que retorne um valor ou True e False, mas não tiver uma variável para receber, isso pode ocasionar em algum problema no funcionamento do código?

Exemplo:

```
def Retorna():
    return False

def Retorna2():
    return 100

Retorna()
Retorna2()
```

Comment: Não, a única coisa que o valor retornado ficará perdido no limbo da memória e você não conseguirá acessá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem problema algum.

EMbora não seja um design tipico da linguagem Python, onde é comum ter funções sem um valor de retorno, é possível que uma função retorne sempre o objeto sobre o qual atuou - o uso desse valor retornado é opcional.

Em Javascript e em algumas bibliotecas de Python é comum retornar sempre o objeto sobre o qual a função atuou - dessa forma você pode encadear outras chamadas direto no valor de retorno. Mas se não tiver outras chamadas, nada acontece.

Não há sequer um gasto adicional de memória - se não houver uma variável para guardar um valor de retorno: assim que ele é retornado, como não tem nenhuma referência pra ele, ele é destruido, e sua memória liberada.